# Is it possible to have a read/write replicas of azure postgresql

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

Azure have brought out azure flexible postgres which allows **read** replicas to a different az but we need a **read/write** solution. Does anybody know of any way to set up read/write replicas in postgres even with a 3rd party solution?
Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Read replicas are read-only. You cannot write to them.
They can be promoted to be a read/write server in the event of a disaster recovery.